# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на inline-кнопку выводили reply-кнопки?

Tags: python, telebot

Вот мой код:

```
import telebot
import webbrowser
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ТОКЕН')

class_9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('9', callback_data='class9')
class_10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('10', callback_data='class10')
class_11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('11', callback_data='class11')
name_user = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    global class_9, class_10, class_11, name_user
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    name_user = message.from_user.first_name
    #class_6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('6', callback_data='class6')
    #class_7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('7', callback_data='class7')
    #class_8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('8', callback_data='class8')
    # markup.row(class_6, class_7, class_8)
    markup.row(class_9, class_10, class_11)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {name_user}!\nВыбери свой класс:', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global class_9, class_10, class_11, name_user
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    class_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('А', callback_data='classA')
    class_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Б', callback_data='classB')
    class_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('В', callback_data='classC')
    nazad = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad')
    if callback.data == 'class9':
        markup.row(class_1, class_2, class_3)
        markup.row(nazad)
        bot.edit_message_text('Выбери литеру:', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'class10':
        markup.row(class_1, class_2)
        markup.row(nazad)
        bot.edit_message_text('Выбери литеру:', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'class11':
        markup.row(class_1, class_2, class_3)
        markup.row(nazad)
        bot.edit_message_text('Выбери литеру:', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'nazad':
        markup.row(class_9, class_10, class_11)
        bot.edit_message_text(f'Привет, {name_user}!\nВыбери свой класс:', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler()
def main_9a():
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    monday_9a = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='monday9a')
    tuesday_9a = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='tuesday9a')
    wednesday_9a = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='wednesday9a')
    thursday_9a = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='thursday9a')
    friday_9a = types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='friday9a')
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('Понедельник', callback_data='monday9a'))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['website'])
def site(message):
    webbrowser.open('САЙТ')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ИНФО')

bot.infinity_polling()
```